# Undefined variable in blade file $status

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I made CRUD, when I edited the data there was an error Undefined variable $status in line 26.what should i do?

this is code in line 26

```
    <form action="<?php echo e(URL::to('/statuses/update' ,$status->id)); ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

this code in controller

```
public function edit(Status $status)
    {
        return view('statuses.edit');
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Status $status)
    {
        $status->update([
            'status_name' => $request->status_name,
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('statuses.index')
                        ->with('success','Berhasil Update !');
    }
```

this index code

```
<table id="table" class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach ($statuses as $status)
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $loop->iteration}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $status->status_name }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <form action="{{ URL::to('/statuses/destroy' ,$status->id) }}" method="POST">
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ URL::to('/statuses/edit' ,$status->id) }}">Edit</a>
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                    </form>
                                    </tbody>
                            @endforeach
```

and this my route

```
 Route::get('/statuses', [StatusController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('statuses/create', [StatusController::class, 'create']);
    Route::get('statuses/create', [StatusController::class, 'create']);
    Route::get('statuses/edit/{id}', [StatusController::class, 'edit']);
    Route::put('statuses/edit/{id}', [StatusController::class, 'store']);
    Route::delete('statuses/delete/{id}', [StatusController::class, 'delete']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not pass the variable to the view:

```
public function edit(Status $status)
    {
        return view('statuses.edit', compact('status'));
    }
```